# How do I use a separate method to call the paint component method and draw a rectangle?

Tags: java, swing, object, user-interface, methods

I am using Swing to create a GUI which would draw a new rectangle every time a method runs.
I want to use variables that would get incremented and continue making new rectangles in a series.
My goal is to give a visual representation of a linked list and to emphasize on the concept that a linked list has a head which points to the next item which points to the next and so on.

I am a beginner with basic knowledge of Java, and I'm just getting started with Swing and creating User interfaces.

```java
void insert(int i, int j) {
    //some code which would create a new rectangle and add to my GUI.
}

// this is my panel class
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    MyPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500)); 
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.setPaint(Color.blue);
        g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        g2D.drawRect(i, j, 100, 50);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Prefer `paintComponent` over `paint` [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  As @MadProgrammer said, pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Comment: work through a tutorial about java language basics first, then go on with basics in Swing - and only if confident with both, go on with custom painting (overriding paint is plain wrong, as @MadProgrammer already hinted at)

Comment: @kleopatra I do know the basics of Java, I'm learning it as a part of my CS course in college . Swing is something that I'm doing on my own, so I'm not exactly sure how to proceed. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score -1):

What you can do:

1. Create a list to store the passed arguments to the `insert(int,int)` method
2. Fill that list in the `insert(int,int)` method
3. the `paintComponents()`-method can loop over the saved values and display them

```java
// records are fairly new to Java. See (*) for what it does
private record Tuple(int i, int j) {}

// this list contains values added by the `insert(int, int)` method
private final List<Tuple> tuples = new ArrayList<>();

private void insert(final int i, final int j) {
    // do some stuff
    // ...

    // save passed values to a list using the helper class "Tuple"
    this.tuples.add(new Tuple(i, j));

    // repaint UI
    this.repaint();
}

@Override
public void paintComponents(final Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    // loop over saved values and do something with their values
    for (final Tuple tuple : this.tuples) {
        // draw rect for saved tuple
        g.drawRect(tuple.i * 10, tuple.j * 10, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

---

(*) records were introduced in Java 14 and they can be used to create data classes in a short way.

They automatically generate Getters, the `equals()`, `hashCode()` and `toString()`-method.

For this example, the record could be be rewritten to:

```java
private class Tuple {
  private final int i;
  private final int j;

  public Tuple(final int i, final int j) {
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
  }
}
```

(we don't *need* `equals()`, `hashCode()` and `toString()`)

Comment: no, in Swing it's plain wrong to override paint

Comment: Why override `Container::paintComponents`? Please note the spelling: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! This is the first time that I heard about records, so that's something new. But as others have pointed out, it seems like overriding paint isn't the right way to solve this problem.

Comment: better - but please make sure that your answer is correct a) the description does not match the code b) adding any tuples does not update the ui